# How did Volkov end up bringing two bullets, the normal one and the inverted one in one magazine and how did he try to shoot?

Tags: plot-explanation, tenet

I have a question about the scene in *Tenet* at Stalsk-12, where Volkov tries to shoot TP in the head.

First of all, it seemed like Volkov ended up bringing two bullets with him and it's unclear how he did that:

1. normal bullet, forward through time, the one that he try to shoot Ives. Then,
2. The inverted bullet that will killed neil.

But then when Volkov was ordered by Sator to shoot TP in the head, he was intent to shoot him, right? Not catching it. Plus the woman scientist explained that "you have to have dropped the bullet" if you want to catch inverted bullet. So in this scene 'you have to have caught the bullet if you want to shoot TP in the head using the inverted one'. But Volkov doesn't know about the bullet, right?

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in one post. Please [**follow the tour**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: The questions seem directly related, though. So this case can probably be resolved by simply rephrasing the question a little, which I just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both bullets fired by Volkov are normal (un-inverted). Inverted bullets are not required to shoot inverted individuals; from an inverted person's perspective, being shot with a normal bullet is equivalent to a normal (un-inverted) person being shot with an inverted bullet, which is shown in the film to result in equivalent penetrating trauma (not counting the toxic effects of the radiation from an inverted bullet).